# Jhipster backend deploy to AWS Beanstalk API Call Failure

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**The backend can be deployed but API call is not working.**

The frontend project and backend project are separated, I am trying to deploy the backend(Spring Boot) project onto AWS Beanstalk using `sub-generator` and everything looks fine:
[image]

I have configured the server port to 5000 [Deploying a Spring Boot Application on AWS Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)
[image]

When I invoke API with Beanstalk Environment URL, it always give me 404 Not Found error.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you configure the `baseHref` in your webpack.common.js to match the expected context-path that the Beanstalk Environment is using?

Comment: @JonRuddell  Hi Jon, thanks for reply. I didn't configure that, it is the default settings: `new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/' })`

Comment: @JonRuddell my frontend and backend are separated, I just deployed backend and can't call API when test with Postman

Comment: Ah. Does the URL you are requesting include the context path?